# Controlling fans via a graphical user interface

Tags: gui, fan, fancontrol

I have been asking myself if there is any gui application to control the fans, as pwmconfig might be a bit too much for a noob like me. There are plenty of those applications for windows, but I couldn't find a single one for linux.

Comment: Are you looking for a UI to configure fancontrol?  Or a UI to manually control your fan speeds?

Comment: Something to configure fancontrol or something that can do the same as fancontrol can do and perform those actions on startup.